# “Where would I...”, and “how would I...” in the future

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

> Where would I go if the world doesn’t help me?

> How would I know if he is a good person?

I know that “how would I know...” describes that ‘I don’t know if he is a good person, so does “where would I go...”also describe there would be no place to go to because the world dosen’t help me? I am not asking you the question but asking myself “where would I go?”.

Comment: The first is a conditional. 'If I were to receive no help, where would I go?'

Answer (score 0):

Actually, "how would I know?" is often used as a rhetorical question to mean that you don't know something.

For example:

> -Where are my car keys?
> -How would I know? They are your keys!

Context should indicate if a question is rhetorical or is inviting an answer. By the fact that you say "the world" doesn't help you, you are omitting all alternatives, so it is obvious you are being rhetorical.